# Android studio does not auto recognize Emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

I used Android studio version 17.0.6
I turn on Emulation device Pixel XL API 30 on Android studio but android studio only show me 3 browsers to select. Thus I cannot debug on Emulator device.

[image]

Image below show the flutter doctor -v

[image]

I deleted platform-tool folder and copied the newest but it did not work.

I selected SDK path on project but it did not work also
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.